# Tkinter Entry - fire a validatecommand event a second time

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using the `validatecommand` option of a Tkinter `Entry` box to pickup the value entered by the user and validate it in a database. This works successfully once per `Entry` widget.

Problem is, the event won't fire again a second time for the same widget, say if a user returns to make a correction. How can I reset validation on an `Entry` widget so it can be executed again if the user returns to the box later?

```
def isOkay(root, why, where, barcode, name):
    
    if (barcode != ''): 
        lookupFromBarcodeSql = "select Manufacturer, Brand, Model, Submodel, Size from Drives where Submodel = %s and Manufacturer = 'Seagate' and Brand != '' and Brand is not null and Model != '' and Model is not null and Submodel != '';"
        lookupFromBarcodeParams = (barcode.strip(),)

        myCursor.execute(lookupFromBarcodeSql, lookupFromBarcodeParams)
        lookupResults = myCursor.fetchall()
        for result in lookupResults:
            print(result[0] + " " + result[1] + " " + result[2] + " " + result[4])
    
checkAgainstDb, = root.register(isOkay)

lidBarCode = Entry(BarCodeFrame, validate="focusout",validatecommand=(checkAgainstDb, '%d','%i','%S','%P','%W'))


The callback function is unfinished code but is only called once, as evidenced by the print statement only firing once.
```

Comment: Please provide a [example] so that we can reproduce your error. It's not as likely that you get an answer to your question if you make others have to write your code to reproduce the problem. See [ask] and the [help] for more information.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include a [mcve]. Tkinter will automatically remove the validation command if it returns anything other than True or False or if you try to modify the widget value inside the validation function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are paths through `isOkay` that do not return `True` or `False`. Validation functions must return a boolean value or it will get disabled.